# Sorting a list of pairs C++

Tags: c++, list, sorting, deque

I am building a system which should take a in a list of pairs, both strings, and sort them into the correct order. In the list they appear:

E,F

C,D

B,C

A,B

D,E

and the output should be 
A,B,C,D,E,F

The system is given a random letter to start with, then iterates through the list and gets the correct next letter using that one. so if given C, it points to D which points to E. Then after it it goes back to C and uses it to find the letter before. Then I am adding it to a deque. Something is going wrong somewhere I suspect in the 2nd loop what means I'm only getting what comes after the letter but not before. However, if I give it E to start with it comes out fine and gets everything before and after.

```
void mm::sort(std::string startName)
{

std::list<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>::const_iterator iterator;

std::string base = startName;
int i = 0;

for (iterator = men.begin(); iterator != men.end(); iterator++)
{

    if ((*iterator).first == base)
    {
        output.push_back(base);
        base = (*iterator).second;

        iterator = men.begin();
        i++;
    }
}

base = output[0];

for (iterator = men.begin(); iterator != men.end(); iterator++)
{

    if ((*iterator).second == base)
    {
        output.push_front(base);
        base = (*iterator).first;

        iterator = men.begin(); 
        i++;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `so if given C, it points to E` Really?  not D?

Comment: My bad, changed it to D

Comment: If the output doesn't depend on the paired structure at all, and ignore duplicates, why not just insert each string into a set? It already does both things you want (sorts and eliminates duplicates).

Comment: In the first loop's `if` statement you have: `iterator = men.begin();`. Now fix your eyes at your `for` loop, specifically how the `for` loop iterates, and keep staring it until you figure out your bug. Remember the golden rule of computer programming: a computer always does exactly what you tell it to do, and not what you want it to do. Keep staring at the `for` loop until you've figured out what exactly you told the computer to do, there.

Comment: I am meaning to go back to the start of the list every time so I can search through from the start and find the next item.

Comment: Look at [Topological_sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Comment: @TRV it would be very helpful if you could create MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think you should `push_front` after (not before) reassigning `base` in your second loop (otherwise, you'll get the same string twice in your list the first time you call push_front). I also feel like you forgot the last `push_back` in your first loop. That said, I can't compile this code (it would have been nice to have a complete and reproducible example), so maybe I'm missing something obvious. Ah, you should also have an infinite loop if there's a cycle in your input (maybe that's what `i` will be for ?it  looks like you erased parts of your function, the return statement for instance).

Comment: Well, of course that you want to do, but that's not what you told the computer to do. You told the computer to set `iterator = men.begin();` inside the `if` loop, and when the loop goes to the next iterator, it increments `iterator`, so you actually end up going back to the 2nd element of your list. If you want to restart the loop from its first element, you will have to change your logic.

Answer (score 0):

1. Flatten the `list<pair<string, string>>` to a `list<string>`
2. sort the `list<string>`
3. remove duplicates from the sorted list.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what he wants. I think he wants [(A,C);(C,B)] to mean A<C<B. His example only happened to use the usual alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

There are easier and efficient ways to do this. Since you insisted and asked to find the error in your program, I solved it for you.

I assumed there are no cycles. Compare this with your sort function and understand why I moved

> iterator++

It's the only major thing you missed.

See below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<utility>
#include<string>

std::list<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> men;
std::list<std::string> output;

void sort(std::string startName)
{

std::list<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>::const_iterator iterator;

std::string base = startName;

for (iterator = men.begin(); iterator != men.end(); )
{

    if ((*iterator).first == base)
    {
        output.push_back(base);
        base = (*iterator).second;
        iterator = men.begin();
    }
    else {
        iterator++;
    }
}
output.push_back(base);   // Another line you missed.(for last element)

base = output.front();

for (iterator = men.begin(); iterator != men.end(); )
{

    if ((*iterator).second == base)
    {
        output.push_front((*iterator).first);
        base = (*iterator).first;

        iterator = men.begin();
    }
    else
        iterator++;
}

}


int main() {
men.push_front(std::make_pair("Five", "Six"));
men.push_front(std::make_pair("One", "Two"));
men.push_front(std::make_pair("Four", "Five"));
men.push_front(std::make_pair("Two", "Three"));
men.push_front(std::make_pair("Three", "Four"));
sort("Three");
for (std::string s : output)
    std::cout<<s<<std::endl;
getchar();
return 0;
}
```